# Youtube iframe issue, only play when clicked with autoplay 1

Tags: html, youtube

We have the following youtube iframe embedded in our application:

```
 <div class="youtube">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%# Eval("YouTubeId") %>?autoplay=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;controls=1&amp;loop=0&amp;playlist&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=1&amp;start=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;color=red&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="poster"><span></span><%# IfImage("Thumbnail",GetBrickImage(Eval("Thumbnail"), "featurevideo", Eval("Title")), "") %></div>
```

We currently display a thumbnail for the video, when the user browses to the site and they click on the thumbnail to play the video the standard Youtube play button appears which makes the user click again which is very annoying.  I changed the autoplay from 0 to 1 which fixed the issue in Firefox, opera, safari, and IE but when viewed on chrome the video starts playing automatically as soon as the page has loaded, but the thumbnail is still visible.  So you don't actually see the video you only hear the content, I'm out of ideas on how to get this to work correctly, has anyone come across this? if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the Chrome issue goes, I'm a little stumped.

However, when using defered video playing I would load the src of the iframe using javascript when the user clicks the Thumbnail. This way the video won't even load until the user wants to view it, which saves on bandwidth and loading time too.